# Unwanted change when using "TextToColumns" twice

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue.

One of my sheets holds a column that contains values stored as text (e.g. value as 1,22 stored as a text). Currently I use the following Code to convert those entries to values:

```
Sub Convert()
    Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth, DecimalSeparator:=","
End Sub
```

If I run the macro once the result is fine. However if I run to macro a second time (after I already converted the text to values with the code shown above). The numbers change their format from the comma "," as the decimal separator to a dot "." as a decimal separator (e.g. 1,22 --> 1.22).

This is a problem, because my region uses the comma.

Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening?

Kind regards
Sombrero

Here Screenshots:

Original data@
[image: Original data]

After first time text2columns:
[image: After first time text2columns]

After second time text2columns:
[image: After second time text2columns]

Comment: Please show us your input data - otherwise it is hard to answert the question.

Comment: Hello Ike,

sure thing. I just uploaded it via swisstransfer. I put the data in Column "K". The sub is called "Convert" like in my example.

https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/78d0ef47-4e30-4545-b1c9-42552c2ef666

Comment: @SombreroEistee Please note that no one will download a potentially dangerous macro enabled file from an unknown source (that is why SO has no file sharing). Also according [ask] everything that is needed to understand your question needs to be in the question itself. Links may disappear after a while and the question gets useless to future readers. Please [edit] your question and add some example data along with a [mcve] of your problem, so everyone can reproduce it.

Comment: Hello PEH,

thank you for your message.

However I don't really know what to do. It is just one line of code. If somebody opens an excel-file and puts enters two numbers in two different cells separated by comma (e.g. 1,22 and 1,55) in a column "K" and runs this oneliner then the result should be the same. 

Maybe screenshots can help?

Comment: PS: Added some screenshots. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Thx, that helped a lot to reproduce it. Same happens here, so I can confirm this behavior. Looks like a bug to me. The actual question is why do you run it twice at all? • If you run it with `DecimalSeparator:="."` as last run it will convert all `.` back to `,`. Does this workaround solve your issue?

Comment: Did you try ``Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "General"`` instead?

Comment: @ElioFernandes It turns the numbers into strings so `.NumberFormat` is useless.

Comment: My region also uses the comma separator and the formula I posted just converts the cells in the range from ``Text`` to ``General``. I tried and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You original data are strings, and running `TextToColumns` converts them into numbers. When you run `TextToColumns` a second time, Excel needs to convert those numbers first into strings.

I can only guess about the internal logic of this conversion, but it wouldn't surprise me if this is not using any regional settings.

Anyhow, I would say it's not a good idea to use the `TextToColumns` command on numeric values. Use a filter to get only the cells containing text:

```
Dim r As Range
set r =  Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
On Error Resume Next     ' To prevent runtime error "No cells found"
Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
If err.Number = 1004 then exit sub
On Error Goto 0
r.TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth, DecimalSeparator:=","
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas! I think that works!